# d3.js: Link correctly the paths of the nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using the d3.js library to paint some nodes and link them, but they don't link them correctly. I have tried too many things but none of them has given me a solution.

[image]

Like you can see in the image the path are linking only in the enter position of the svg:rect.

```
 nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });



  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", 30)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + " " + (d.occurences || ""); })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);



 nodeEnter.append("svg:image")

   .attr('width', 0)
   .attr('height', 0)
     .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d.icon; });


  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });



  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -12.5)
    .attr("width", function(d){ return  (getWidthOfText(d.name, 'Helvetica Neue', 14)+getWidthOfText(d.ocurrences, 'Helvetica Neue', 14))+30;})
    .attr("height", 25)
    //.style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
     .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");


  nodeUpdate.select("text")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  nodeUpdate.select("image")
     .attr("x", 6)
   .attr("y", -7)
  .attr('width', 20)
  .attr('height', 15)
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)

    .attr("height", 1)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });


  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  vis.selectAll("image")
   .append("svg:title")
   .text(function(d) { return "Descripción: "+d.description+"\n\nComentarios: "+d.comment});

// Update the links…
var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  })
.transition()

  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);


 // Transition links to their new position.
 link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
link.exit().transition()

  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", function(d) {

    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  })
  .remove();

// Stash the old positions for transition.
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.y0 = d.y;

});
```

Is there any way to move the paths to get the nodes correctly linked?

Comment: How are you determining the width of each node `rect`?  Update your question with your code that produces each node.

Comment: As you said me I have updated the code @Mark

Comment: Your problem seems to be that the link origin is set to the source node (x,y). If you calculate the draw distance of each node, you add it to the current values and it should work.

Comment: Okay, but where is the source node point set?? Because I think it is calculated automatically by the library with the projection function.

Comment: Finally I set the connecting point in the center of the node, I couldn't do it like I wanted.